# Is every ideal of a unit regular ring unit regular?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, von-neumann-algebras

A ring $R$ with unity $1_R$ is unit regular if for any $a\in R$, $a=aua$ for some unit element $u\in R$.  An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is a unit regular ideal if for any $x\in I$, there exists $u\in R$ such that $x=xux$.

My probem: Is every ideal of a unit regular ring unit regular?   If not, are there examples of regular ideals of a unit regular ring that are not unit regular?

Comment: Why exactly you can't just take the element $u \in R$ which exists since $R$ is unit regular?

Comment: See http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2003/9-15.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've written, it's trivially the case that:

1. an ideal contained in a unit-regular ideal is unit-regular; and
2. the ordinary definition of "unit-regular ring" is just that $R$ is a unit-regular ideal of $R$; therefore
3. Every ideal of a unit-regular ring is a unit-regular ideal.